# SQL: Find if the column values are in right order

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with StudentID, Date and CourseStatus.

If I order by StudentID and Date, the CourseStatus should only be in particular order (ENROLLED -> STARTED -> FINISHED -> TESTPASSED).  But there are some StudentIDs where CourseStatus values are in incorrect order.

How to find such StudentIDs where CourseStatus is not strictly in expected order when ordered by date?

Example:

```
StudentID - Date         - CourseStatus
---------------------------------------
Student1  -  2019-01-01  - "ENROLLED"
Student1  -  2019-03-01  - "STARTED"
Student1  -  2019-05-01  - "FINISHED"
Student1  -  2019-08-01  - "TESTPASSED"
Student4  -  2019-02-15  - "ENROLLED"
Student4  -  2019-03-30  - "FINISHED"   <-- Incorrect value / sequence
Student4  -  2019-05-01  - "STARTED"    <-- Incorrect value / sequence
Student4  -  2019-09-01  - "TESTPASSED"
```

```
SQL Output should be
Student4  -  2019-02-15  - "ENROLLED"
Student4  -  2019-03-30  - "FINISHED"
Student4  -  2019-05-01  - "STARTED"
Student4  -  2019-09-01  - "TESTPASSED"
```

Comment: Sort by StudentID, YTDPayment, Date

Comment: Use a session variable to hold the course status from the previous row, and check that the next one is in the proper sequence

Comment: Is `YTDPayment` supposed to be `CourseStatus`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are runing MySQL 8.0, you can use window functions for this:

```
select 
    StudentID,
    Date,
    YTDPayment
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        s.seq
        lag(s.seq) over(partition by StudentID order by Date) lag_seq,
        lead(s.seq) over(partition by StudentID order by Date) lead_seq,
    from mytable t
    inner join (
        select 0 seq, 'ENROLLED' CourseStatus
        union all select 1, 'STARTED' 
        union all select 2, 'FINISHED' 
        union all select 3, 'TESTPASSED' 
    ) s on s.CourseStatus = t.CourseStatus
) t
where not (
    (seq = lag_seq + 1 or seq = 0 and lag_seq = 3 or lag_seq is null)
    and (seq + 1 = lead_seq or seq = 3 and lead_seq = 0 or lead_seq is null)
)
```

The subquery uses `lead()` and `lag()` to recover the previous and next status - it is tedious to manipulate string for sequence comparisons here, so I used a mapping table that translates the strings to integer numbers.

The outer query the filters on records that do not follow the pre-defined sequence. I enumerated all possible case (increasing sequence, end of a sequence and start of a new one, first/last record per student).

Answer (score 0):

If you could live with the values in a single row, you can use aggregation:

```
select studentid,
       group_concat(coursestatus order by date) as statuses
from t
group by student_id
having statuses <> 'ENROLLED,STARTED,FINISHED,TESTPASSED';
```

To get the original rows, you can use a `join`:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select studentid,
             group_concat(coursestatus order by date) as statuses
      from t
      group by student_id
      having statuses <> 'ENROLLED,STARTED,FINISHED,TESTPASSED'
     ) ss
     on t.studentid = ss.studentid;
```